# Create an Apex trigger to update the value of a picklist field

Tags: apex, trigger

I'm trying to use an apex trigger to update the value of a picklist field on an Opportunity field related object. I would like to change the Opportunity field called “Status” (picklist field) to “Commit” anytime someone updates the Stage field to “Closed” for a specific opportunity type.

Does anyone have any sample code for changing picklist field values in Apex? Thanks!!!

Comment: Why not just use a workflow rule and field update?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a trigger to do that, you need a workflow. It is best to use a declarative approach when possible.

From Setup on your top right corner go to:

1. Build
2. Create
3. Workflow & Approvals
4. Workflow Rules
5. Click on **"New Rule"**
6. Object **"Opportunity"** - click new
7. Enter a **"Rule Name"**
8. On the **"Evaluation Criteria"** select **"created and every time it's edited"**
9. For **"Rule Criteria"** select the field **"Stage"**
10. Operator **"equals"**
11. Value **"Closed"**

Now click **save and next**.

On the next page you declare the field that you want to get updated.

1. Click on **"Add Workflow Action"**
2. Select **New Field Update**
3. Give it a name and select the **"Field to Update"** , after that the value.
4. Down you will be able to insert **"A specific value"**. There you select the value you want to insert.
5. Click **save**, **done**, and **"Activate"** on the last page.

That should do it.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad that it helps.